# How to push the HTML file back to the web page from my python

Tags: python

My task is to download a webpage in html format and upload back to the same page after few modifications.

I'm able to download the code and did the required modifications to my downloaded HTML, but struct to upload back to the same page.

Here the page is in server, but i want to view my modifications before uploading in the server. i'm able to see my output HTML file by running the html file, please help me to view the output in the same web page

Comment: In short, it can't be done. Long answer: I think you need to get some clarifications on how the web works, in the sense of browser (client) to server communication works. Any web page has a unique URL that refers to the content *on the server*. If you want to see a page at a different location (the one you downloaded), you either do what you are already doing (loading it locally), or you upload it to the server and refresh. Only other option is to do some manipulation *in browser*, but that is more far fetched for your use case I think.

Comment: Do you have ftp access to the server that's running the webpage?

Comment: first of all thanks for the response, @Kostas Charitidis, yes i have access to the server.

Comment: @sal hello, as i'm new to the language, i'm trying that it is possible. Here i want to know few more, -How a browser interact with server?(as you suggest), what are the parameters that i have to pass if i directly deploy the program in server. Thanks for your patience in advance

Comment: There is confusion on what you are asking here. At one point you mention `but i want to view my modifications before uploading in the server`. And here you are asking how to deploy to the server. If you want to deploy the new file to the server, and have FTP access, then you can use what @KostasCharitidis wrote in his answer. To learn more about server/client, best is you do your own research. Keywords to look for: "http protocol", "web server", "web client", and so on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have FTP access to the server here is an example with the ftplib package to upload a file:

```
# encoding:utf-8

from ftplib import FTP
import os
import fileinput

ftp = FTP()
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.connect('your ftp server', 21)
ftp.login('username', 'password')

ftp.cwd('/images')


def ftp_upload(localfile, remotefile):
    fp = open(localfile, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % os.path.basename(localfile), fp, 1024)
    fp.close()
    print("after upload " + localfile + " to " + remotefile)


localdir = "C:\\tmp"


def upload_img(file):
    ftp_upload(localdir + "\\" + file, file)


lastlist = []

for line in fileinput.input(localdir + "\\new_file.html"):
    lastlist.append(line.rstrip("\n"))

currentlist = os.listdir(localdir)

newfiles = list(set(currentlist) - set(lastlist))

if len(newfiles) == 0:
    print("No files need to upload")
else:
    for needupload in newfiles:
        print("uploading " + localdir + "\\" + needupload)
        upload_img(needupload)
        with open(localdir + "\\new_file.html", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(needupload + "\n")

ftp.quit()
```

Hope it helps!